# Impact on bundles that are too big?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, webpack

I recently created a Vue.js project. I've added a few packages, including [Firebase](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase) (I have the modular v9 package, so it has tree shaking enabled), and [Rive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase). When building my application, I see that my final bundle is about 800-900KiB, while webpack suggests keeping it under 240. I created a report and I saw that Rive and Firebase were the main culprits of the big filesize (together they were about 750KiB). Rive is a package still in early development so it wouldn't surprise me if it wasn't optimized for production, but the fact that firebase also used so much space (specially considering I used v9) made me wonder whether I did something wrong?

Anyway, my question is, is having a bundle of around 1MiB bad? How badly would it impact user?

Answer (score 1):

1MB isn't bad, it may take slightly longer to load initially, considering most jpg images you see online can be up to 1MB each easily. most users with modern bandwidth connections will not notice any negative side effects.

It's just something you should keep in mind.